# Who is responsible for an intra-hospital ambulance?

Tags: united-states, health

Several months ago, I went to the emergency room. I called an ambulance, which took me to Local Hospital (Branch A). While there, the hospital said they did not have the facilities to treat me, and moved me to Local Hospital (Branch B). Local Hospital contracted an Independent Ambulance company to transport me from Branch A to Branch B.

Ambulance company is billing me for the full amount, because my insurance says it's not covered. I've been going back and forth with the insurance company over the last several months. Now it has gone to a collections agency.

Collections agency is telling me that it falls under Good Samaritan laws, and that I am responsible for the full amount.

Is this correct? Where is the burden of responsibility for this bill?

Comment: As a general principle, you are responsible for the cost of all medical care provided to you.  Whether your insurance company pays for it, or reimburses you, is between you and them.